# How to verify email from pc to mobile

Tags: laravel, email-verification, laravel-authentication, laravel-package

I'm using Laravel's auth package, and I am trying to configure Controllers/Auth/VerificationController.php to try to redirect the user to the homepage. Basically, I will send an email verification request via desktop then try to click the link that has been sent to my email using my phone but when clicked it only goes to the login page and not home.

I'm currently using Hostinger for the site and the verification works if I click verify using the same device that I used to send the verification link.

Comment: This is because you did your registration in your desktop. In your desktop it is authenticated but not verified(e.g. column in db is null or 0 or any other way you tried to verify). That is why when you click on the confirm link, it will update to verified. In case of your phone clicking the confirmation URL, since the session in the phone is not authorized, it will redirect to the login page as expected.

Comment: is there any way I can possibly make it verify using phone?

Comment: You can update your verification controller to also fetch the user before verifying.

Comment: you would have to create a signed url and encode in it some unique id, Laravel makes this quite easy, in order to be able to get the user from the url, rather than the session, in a safe way. The url needs to be signed so that no one can edit it after it has been sent.